# WordPress Custom Structure permalinks breaks after migrating site to new domain and server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, iis, windows-server-2012

I had my WP on a site `mysite1.com` and am migrating it to `mysite2.com`, hosted on a different server. I simple ran a find-and-replace in the database, `mysite1.com -> mysite2.com`, and **the homepage mysite2.com now works fine** but all the subpages (`mysite2.com/subpage1`, `mysite2.com/subpage2`, `mysite2.com/subpage1/thing?id=1`, etc.) do not work. I'm using the Custom Structure `http://mysite2.com/%postname%/`, which worked just fine on `mysite1.com`. **All the other Permalink structures work on `mysite2.com`**, I might add. It's when I switch back to the custom structure that the subpages 404.

Could this have something to do with needing to configure my new server or `php.ini` or anything?

Any ideas on what may be the cause of the problem and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: did you copied old `.haccess` from old hosting folder to the new place?

Comment: @Alex Yes there 16 htcaccess folders buried in the WordPress source files and I've verified that they were all transferred over

Comment: @SpaghettiCoder first change the permission of your .htaccess file and then try changing the permalink i think it should work

Comment: What is my .htaccess file? Like I said, there are 16. Is there a master one? Can you give me some details on what exactly I need to do?

Comment: @SpaghettiCoder are all the .htaccess file in the root directory of your website or in seperate folders?

Comment: @NitinJohnson I just looked an all 16 of the htaccess files are inside a folder for a plugin that I'm not using. So there are no htaccess files anywhere besides there.

Comment: @SpaghettiCoder there should be a main .htaccess file in the root of your website and not inside the folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93201/discussion-between-spaghetti-coder-and-nitin-johnson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try putting an .htaccess file on the root of your wordpress. Then change its permission to 755 and the change the permalink structure to postname.

Here is sample .htacess file code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite2.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite2.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Evidently you can't use .htaccess files in IIS 7 http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_Permalinks_Without_mod_rewrite

Comment: That's related to my problem

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: Didn't work. Plus, my homepage, which works, uses `get_site_url()`. I don't believe there is a problem with it not knowing the base url. (For the record, I didn't downvote you; that was someone else, appartently)