# The mere PRESENCE of a web.config causes 500 Internal server error on my WordPress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, iis, iis-8

This is driving me nuts! I've literally spent 5 hours on a problem I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308056/wordpress-custom-structure-permalinks-breaks-after-migrating-site-to-new-domain). With the permalink structure set to the custom

```
mysite.com/%postname%/
```

the homepage `mysite.com` works but none of the subpages do. I've tried creating a web.config with the contents shown on on post 3 of https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-indexphp-in-permalinks-using-iis-8, but the mere presence of a `web.config` at the root causes 500 Internal server errors everything. I've put an ***empty*** `web.config` there and that causes errors 500 on every page as well. I have Windows Server 2012 and IIS8, by the way.

To recap:

- Without a `web.config`, I can access the homepage like `mysite.com`, but I get a `404` on any subpages such as `mysite.com/mysubpage`. Those subpages do surface with `mysite.com/index.php/mysubpage`, however.
- Adding an empty `web.config` or one with the contents shown on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-indexphp-in-permalinks-using-iis-8 and I've also tried the one on http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_Permalinks_Without_mod_rewrite with no success. 500 on every page.
- According to http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress, I can't use mod_rewrite in IIS8.

I'm dying here :(

Comment: Are you sure you're running a Windows web server?

Comment: @DarylGill I figured out the problem. I need to install URL Rewrite 2 in IIS. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: @SpaghettiCoder Post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed! Installing URL Rewrite 2 (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) was the magic elixer.

Comment: Spanghetti, How did you installed URL Rewrite 2 on server?